# Appending two dataframes - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_extension'

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes (df1 and df2) which look like:

df1

```
Quarter Body    Total requests  Requests Processed  …   Requests on-hold 
Q3 2019    A                93                  92  …                  0
Q3 2019    B               228                 210  …                  0
Q3 2019    C               180                 178  …                  0
Q3 2019    D                31                  31  …                  0
Q3 2019    E               555                 483  …                  0
```

df2

```
Quarter Body    Total requests  Requests Processed  …   Requests on-hold 
Q2 2019    A                50                  50  …                  0
Q2 2019    B               191                 177  …                  0
Q2 2019    C               186                 185  …                  0
Q2 2019    D                35                  35  …                  0
Q2 2019    E               344                 297  …                  0
```

I am tring to append df2 onto df2 to create df3:

df3

```
Quarter Body    Total requests  Requests Processed  …   Requests on-hold 
Q3 2019    A                93                  92  …                  0
Q3 2019    B               228                 210  …                  0
Q3 2019    C               180                 178  …                  0
Q3 2019    D                31                  31  …                  0
Q3 2019    E               555                 483  …                  0
Q2 2019    A                50                  50  …                  0
Q2 2019    B               191                 177  …                  0
Q2 2019    C               186                 185  …                  0
Q2 2019    D                35                  35  …                  0
Q2 2019    E               344                 297  …                  0
```

using:

```
df3= df1.append(df2)
```

but get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_extension'
```

the full error trace is:

```
File "<ipython-input-405-e3e0e047dbc0>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/2019_Q3/Code.py', wdir='C:/2019_Q3')

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/2019_Q3/Code.py", line 420, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/2019_Q3/Code.py", line 319, in main
    df3= df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6692, in append
    sort=sort)

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 229, in concat
    return op.get_result()

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 426, in get_result
    copy=self.copy)

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 2056, in concatenate_block_managers
    elif is_uniform_join_units(join_units):

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\concat.py", line 379, in is_uniform_join_units
    all(not ju.is_na or ju.block.is_extension for ju in join_units) and

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\concat.py", line 379, in <genexpr>
    all(not ju.is_na or ju.block.is_extension for ju in join_units) and

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_extension'
```

using:

```
df3= pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

gives me a error:

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

the full error trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-406-e3e0e047dbc0>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/2019_Q3/Code.py', wdir='C:/2019_Q3')

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/2019_Q3/Code.py", line 421, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/2019_Q3/Code.py", line 321, in main
    finalCSV = pd.concat([PreviousCSVdf, df], ignore_index=True)

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 228, in concat
    copy=copy, sort=sort)

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 381, in __init__
    self.new_axes = self._get_new_axes()

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 448, in _get_new_axes
    new_axes[i] = self._get_comb_axis(i)

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 469, in _get_comb_axis
    sort=self.sort)

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\api.py", line 70, in _get_objs_combined_axis
    return _get_combined_index(obs_idxes, intersect=intersect, sort=sort)

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\api.py", line 117, in _get_combined_index
    index = _union_indexes(indexes, sort=sort)

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\api.py", line 183, in _union_indexes
    result = result.union(other)

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2332, in union
    indexer = self.get_indexer(other)

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2740, in get_indexer
    raise InvalidIndexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely'
```

Both `df1` and `df2` have identical numbers of columns and column names.  How would I append df1 and df2?

Comment: Pandas version? Looks like a bug, uninstall and reinstall pandas.

Comment: Can you check for duplicate column names in your datasets?

Comment: you have a typo somewhere or something.  I'm guessing that `df2` isn't a dataframe at all and is `None`.  Otherwise both `append` and `concat` should work.

Comment: Thanks piRSquared.  How would I change df2 to a dataframe?

Comment: My guess cannot be correct.  `df2 = None; df1.append(df2)` actually works.  Hmm.

Comment: Try this `from importlib import reload; import pandas as pd; reload(pd); df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1); df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2); df1.append(df2)`

Comment: If `append` isn't working then your pandas is broken.  I wouldn't trust any other method either.  I'd fix your pandas first.

Answer (score 1):

This tends to happen when you have duplicate columns in one or both of datasets.

Also, for general use its easier to go with [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True) # ignore_index will reset index for you
```

And for the InvalidIndexError you can remove duplicate rows:

```
df1 = df1.loc[~df1.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
df2 = df2.loc[~df2.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

Comment: Thanks zipa - the above gives me a InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects error.  I've edited the body of the question to include the full trace

Comment: @Stacey I've added my suggestion for that error as well

Answer (score 0):

I'll make this short and sweet. I had this same issue.

The issue is not caused by duplicate column names but instead by **duplicate column names with different data types**.

Swapping to `pd.concat` will not fix this issue for you if you don't address the data types first.